# What does 'if $variable {}' mean in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

If I have the following if statement in puppet:

```
if $variable {

   do something

}
```

What does this mean? Is it if $variable is true? If it exists? If it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation.

“If” statements
“If” statements take a boolean condition and an arbitrary block of Puppet code, and will only execute the block if the condition is true. They can optionally include elsif and else clauses.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_conditional.html#if-statements

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_visual_index.html is an excellent place to start in the docs if you're working with manifests and the Puppet DSL. It describes all of the common structures and keywords you'll see.